# Умножение матриц метод

Tags: java

Нужно сделать умножение матриц.
Есть класс Matrix и внутри него есть метод

```
public String mulArray(Matrix arr1, Matrix arr2)
{
    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.getHeight(); i++) {        // rows from m1
        for(int j = 0; j < arr2.getWidth(); j++) {     // columns from m2
            for(int k = 0; k < arr2.getWidth(); k++) { // columns from m1
                a[i][j] += arr1.getValue(i, k) * arr2.getValue(k, j);

            }
            result += a[i][j] + "\t";
        }
        result += "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вызов метода в основном потоке:

```
Matrix a1 = new Matrix(strOne.length, strTwo[0].length);
Matrix a2 = new Matrix(strOne2.length, strTwo2[0].length);
Matrix res = new Matrix(strTwo.length, strTwo2[0].length);
a1.loadStr(strTwo);
a2.loadStr(strTwo2);

res.mulArray(a1, a2);
t3.setText(res.toString());
```

Метод loadStr(String) - загружает массив в экземпляр класса 
В результате выполнения данные считаются неверно. Результат выходит верным только тогда, когда обе матрицы квадратные. Помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код не совпадает с комментариями.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.getHeight(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < arr2.getWidth(); j++) {
        a[i][j] = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < arr1.getWidth(); k++) { // not arr2.getWidth()
            a[i][j] += arr1.getValue(i, k) * arr2.getValue(k, j);
        }
    }
}
```